# Why does Scala ConcurrentMap.putIfAbsent always try to put?

Tags: java, scala, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

The [ConcurrentMap](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-mutable-collection-classes.html#operations-in-class-concurrentmap) section in the docs claim:

> m putIfAbsent(k, v)   Adds key/value binding k -> v unless k is already
>   defined in m

but in reality, I found `putIfAbsent` always tries to insert `v`. The way to get around this is to use `getOrElseUpdate`, but is this really a bug, or am I missing something?

My code is the following:

```
val instanceMap: ConcurrentMap[Address, (MongodExecutable, MongodProcess)] =
    (new JavaConcurrentMap[Address, (MongodExecutable, MongodProcess)]()).asScala

def start(host: String = DefaultAddress.host, port: Int = DefaultAddress.port): MongodProcess = {
  val addr = Address(host, port)
  instanceMap.putIfAbsent(addr, { // this block is ALWAYS executed
    val mongodExecutable = starter.prepare(mongodConfig(host, port))
    val mongod = mongodExecutable.start()
    logProcessInfo(mongod)

    (mongodExecutable, mongod)
  })

  instanceMap(addr)
    ._2
}
```

Comment: `putIfAbsent` takes a value, not a lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`putIfAbsent` does evaluate the value of `k, v` because value is not a function/lambda.

Example below

**original concurrent map**

```
scala> import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap

scala> new ConcurrentHashMap[String, String]()
res0: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[String,String] = {}
```

**insert key1** - successful insertion returns `null`

```
scala> res0.putIfAbsent("127.0.0.1", "mongod-process1")
res1: String = null

scala> res0
res2: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[String,String] = {127.0.0.1=mongod-process1}
```

**insert key2**  - successful insertion returns `null`

```
scala> res0.putIfAbsent("127.0.0.2", "mongod-process2")
res3: String = null

scala> res0
res4: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[String,String] = {127.0.0.2=mongod-process2, 127.0.0.1=mongod-process1}
```

**try to insert key1 again** - failed insertion returns value1

```
scala> res0.putIfAbsent("127.0.0.1", { println("evaluating mongod-process"); "mongod-process1-again" } )
evaluating mongod-process
res7: String = mongod-process1
```

**final map**

```
scala> res0
res8: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[String,String] = {127.0.0.2=mongod-process2, 127.0.0.1=mongod-process1}
```

***Also, note `putIfAbsent` has null check on key value at the beginning(`ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011`) so which will have to evaluate the value anyway.***

```
scala> res0.putIfAbsent("127.0.0.1", { println("evaluating mongod-process"); null } )
evaluating mongod-process
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011)
  at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1535)
  ... 29 elided
```

Comment: I should've looked at the source. `def putIfAbsent(k: A, v: B): Option[B]` and `override def getOrElseUpdate(key: A, op: =>B): B` makes it clear as day. Although, the Scaladoc for `getOrElseUpdate` claims that it returns an `Optional`, which is wrong.